# Scraping and Storing in CSV file(by managing text obtained)

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup, storage, slice

[image: Example of data that is to be stored.]
The figure is given to show the output after requesting the URL and removing all the div element tags. I now need to store the data of Area, Bedroom, Location, Price, the floor in a CSV file. So how can I do it I only know python's function and method for doing it and how can I perform Indexing in such output?

[Output by some manipulation done in URL request which is to be stored in CSV file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCYYv.png)

1. List item

Comment: You will probably have a better time, if instead of getting gid of all the html, you use it to iterate over the items and select properties based on ids, names, tags etc

Comment: I downvoted your question since it not clear at all. also posting images is not helpful at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@shivani Karna, there are many options here. Here are two approaches I would consider:

1. open a file a context manager to write to and write each found element on a new line:

https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_write.asp

2. parse the elements into a dictionary and then write the contents to a pandas dataframe, then to a csv file for a readable format:

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html